# how to get python to return a list?

Tags: python, regex, list, return

So I'm writing a python script that will clean file names of useless and unwanted characters, but I'm running into a problem, I can't seem to figure out how to return a list or dictionary with all of the items in it that I iterated over. it only returns the first item I iterated over. this is my first time writing in python. any help would be greatly appreciated. I'm mostly writing this to learn. the clean_title() method is the one I'm trying to return from. and I call it at the bottom.

```
import os
import re

# here is how all my video files will look after this
# show name Season 1 Episode 1

filename = os.listdir("E:/Videos/TV/tv-show")



def clean_title(filename):
    name = {}
    for title in filename:
        n_title = title.split('.')
        index = [i for i, item in enumerate(n_title) if re.search('\w\d{2}\w\d{2}', item)]
        if len(index) > 0:
            name = {'title':n_title[0:index[0]], 'ep_info':n_title[index[0]]}
            return name


def get_show_name(filename):
    pass


def update_title():
    #show_title = get_show_name + ' ' + get_episode_info
    #print show_title


if __name__=="__main__":
    test = clean_title(filename)
    print test
```

Comment: if you want to add something to a list, use somelist.append(something).  In your case you've created the list, "season_ep_info", so calling season_ep_info.append("something") will add "something" to that list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two distinct problems.

The first is that you're returning from inside your loop, so you will only have processed a single iteration of the loop when you hit the `return` statement.  That's why it looks like you're getting the first iterated value when, in fact, you're never reaching the other iterations.

You can fix this by out-denting the `return` statement to the correct level.

The second problem is in the way you're accruing your results to return from `clean_title()`.  You are only ever storing a single cleaned title in the `name` variable.  Each time through the loop you're overwriting the previously calculated title with the new one from that iteration.  Even if you fix the `return` issue, the current version would then return the *last* title you computed.

You can accrue your results in either a list or a dictionary.  If a list, you initialize with `name = []` and add new titles with `name.append(title_goes_here)`.  If you want to accrue your results in a dictionary, you initialize with `name = {}` and add new titles with `name[index_goes_here] = title_goes_here`.  Note that in the case of a dictionary you need to have some logical key value (usually an integer or string) that you will use to recover the value later on.

Finally, I have to add that I find your use of singular case (`filename`, `title`, `clean_title`) for plural objects and actions to be confusing.  I'd call a list of file names `filenames`, and so on.

Comment: thank you so much this was extremely helpful. I will work on making clearer names for thing. I appreciate the tips.

Answer (score 1):

You're returning after having looked at only the first `title` in `filename`

```
def clean_title(filename):
    # ...
    for title in filename:
        # ...
        if len(index) > 0:
            # ...
            return name
```

I suggest making `clean_title` take only a single filename, and looping through each file as follows:

```
filenames = os.listdir("E:/Videos/TV/tv-show")
for filename in filenames:
    new_filename = clean_title(filename)
    # Rename file
```

Answer (score 1):

The loop will exit as soon as it hits the return.  I suspect what you want to do is

```
def clean_title(filename):
    names = []
    for title in filename:
        n_title = title.split('.')
        index = [i for i, item in enumerate(n_title) if re.search('\w\d{2}\w\d{2}', item)]
        if len(index) > 0:
            names.append({'title':n_title[0:index[0]], 'ep_info':n_title[index[0]]})
    return names
```

which will return a `list` of `dict` objects with two keys, `title` and `ep_info`, each.

Answer (score 1):

1. your indentation of `return name` is wrong, pull it out to be at the
   same level as `name={}` statement
2. `title` should not be a string it should a variable from the `for loop`

It is currently under if condition, hence as soon as the condition is true, after processing the statements in the condition return will be executed

```
def clean_title(filename):
    name_list = []
    for title in filename:
        n_title = title.split('.')
        index = [i for i, item in enumerate(n_title) if re.search('\w\d{2}\w\d{2}', item)]
        if len(index) > 0:
            # you should store the dictionary in the lists, as all the dictionaries will contain the common keys of `ep_info`
            name_list.append({title:n_title[0:index[0]], 'ep_info':n_title[index[0]]})
    return name_list # look here
```